# requestAnimationFrame returning 70fps on Desktop

Tags: javascript, performance, game-development

I'm working with an NES emulator, and noticed the audio and gameplay were extremely fast.  I then figured out the requestAnimationFrame method on my desktop returns ~70-71 fps while my Samsung s20 returns 60 fps, making the emulator run correctly.  Does anybody know why I am getting to many FPS on my desktop? This is an issue with game development. Is my only solution to use a FPS limiting function?

Comment: The gameplay should be made independent on the FPS. It should be time based.

Comment: I don't know how that's possible. The gameplay is set by the game loop which is controlled by requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: [Fix Your Timestep!](https://www.gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) is a great article on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Bad things happen when movement is tied directly to frames/FPS. As a solution to this, we can track the time between the current frame and the last frame (called delta time) in order to calculate the amount of movement, meaning this also works in cases of frame drops.

At the beginning of each frame, after running requestAnimationFrame, store the current time in a variable and calculate the difference in time, e.g.

```js
let currentTime = Date.now();
let deltaTime = currentTime - startTime;
startTime = currentTime;
```

(you'll need to define startTime as Date.now() at the start of your program)

You could then use the deltaTime value as a scalar for movements, or whatever you need in your solution. You could also subtract the expected frame time (1000/fps) from the delta time to figure out how delayed/in advance the frame was.

Have a nice day!

Comment: How would you use the delta time as a scaler for moving a character on screen?

Comment: @CalebPrenger Say, for example, you had a character move 10 pixels per frame. If you wanted to use delta time here, you can simply multiply the amount per frame by the delta time. This probably means the existing value (10) would be a different speed than usual, so you'd need to tweak the values. For example, at 60 fps the expected time per frame would be 16.7 milliseconds, meaning to match the speed of 10 pixels with delta time, you'd want a value around 0.6 if I'm not mistaken, meaning the character should move `0.6 * deltaTime` per frame. Experiment until it's right.

Comment: I've never seen anything like this described in any game development tutorial for web.... This is confusing lol.